# Using python map to replace all floats in a list with rounded floats of type str

Tags: python, list, optimization

I have a function that takes a list of floats and returns the same list of floats except they have exactly 4 digits after the decimal, as strings

Currently it is simply

```
for i in range(len(floats)):
   floats[i] = "%.4f" %floats[i]
```

Which does the job.

But can I do this using the map function (since http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips says using map is faster)

I call this function several thousand times and from the profile results it is one of the functions that takes up more time.

Comment: There's an algorithmic problem for me: if your list **float** isn't modified during execution, you have to change its values only one time; but I think (and hope) it's not the case, so I conclude the list **float** change during execution. If the list completely changes (=all the values or the majority of them) at each modification, then the treatment of the list must concern all the values, as you already do; but if only certain values are changing, it could be interesting to do the treatment at the moment they are changed, not at the moment they are needed. What case is yours ?

Comment: All values will be changed to floats. All original values in the list will be integers or floats. They are changed when I pass the list in so that I know they will be floats when I retrieve them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` is only faster if you use built-in functions (or at least it was when I read about it once ;)). You could use list comprehension though:

```
pattern = "%.4f"
floats = [pattern % i for i in floats]
```

Note that `map` and list comprehension will create a new list, whereas the `for` loop won't. This might be relevant.

Depending on the rest of your application, if possible, you should format the numbers when you add them to the list.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1247486/115845) discusses the performance of `map` vs list comprehension. In summary, `map` can be fractionally faster than list comprehension when `lambda` is not needed for creating ad-hoc functions.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the baseline:

```
python -m timeit 
    "from random import randint; 
     floats = [randint(0, 1000000)/1000.0 for unused in range(10000)]" 
    "for i in range(len(floats)): 
     floats[i] = '%.4f' % floats[i]"
10 loops, best of 3: 48.7 msec per loop
```

Interestingly, the new-style string formatting is a bit slower. Using `'{0:5.4f}'.format(floats[i])` gives 54 msec per loop. The same happens when using `xrange` instead of `range`.

The next improvement suggested by several others is to use a list comprehension:

```
python -m timeit 
    "from random import randint; 
     floats = [randint(0, 1000000)/1000.0 for unused in range(10000)]" 
    "floats = ['%.4f' % f for f in floats]"
10 loops, best of 3: 48.1 msec per loop
```

Surprisingly (at least to me), this is not significantly faster! However, @Felix King already mentioned that list comprehensions would only be faster when using a builtin function.

I really don't have any other ideas about how to make this faster, so I would suggest, if the memory usage is OK for you, use the list comprehension, as it is more readable, and thus more pythonic.

Comment: I also tested `format = "{0:5.4f}".format` and `floats = map(format, floats)` and it was 50% slower than the old string formatting and a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use map then the following sample can be used:

```
map(lambda x: "%.4f" % x, [random() for i in xrange(10)])
```

However @Felix is right and list comprehension will be faster:

```
["%.4f" % x for x in [random() for i in xrange(10)]]
```

Also it is not very clear and if your list can contains not only floats and you want to leave them as is you can do the following:

```
["%.4f" % x if isinstance(x, float) else x for x in listValues]
```

Or if you would like to leave only str floats then:

```
["%.4f" % x for x in listValues if isinstance(x, float)]
```

Comment: ? So - what i am doing wrong? Is this really difficult to write comment during downvoting to help people understand their issues? Is it so?

Comment: I support your comment. Downvotes without explanation is a frustrating loafer's practice

Comment: Thank you for understanding @eyquem - downvoting without explanation will not teach me or anybody else - and absolutely useless for community.